# Can an image in a container scale from its center?

Tags: css, image, crop

Here I have an image that scales as you widen the browser window until it reaches 600px tall, the maximum height of its parent container. At this point, the image is cropped relative to the top of the image. Is it possible to have the image vertically centered in its parent container, so that the image scales from its center? It needs to remain an image, and not a background image.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .full-width {
            max-height: 600px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        img.full {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="full-width">
        <img class="full" src="http://toprival.com/temp/panda/images/panda.jpg" />
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
img.full {
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
```

It moves the image top down 50% of the container height and then moves it back up by 50% of the image height, thereby centering it vertically.

However, the container element needs a defined height and a `position` setting of `relative` for this to work.

...and you can do the same for horizontal centering: `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`

Comment: And img.full needs position:absolute. Thanks!